# Spinbox getting vanished when i go to other frame and come back to the same

Tags: python, tkinter

I have created a spinbox on frame1 and going to frame2 by clicking NEXT, From frame2 going back to frame 1 by clicking BACK button. By the time spinbox widget getting disappear. what could be the reason?

```
from Tkinter import *
def swap_frame(frame):
    frame.tkraise()

root = Tk()
root.geometry("900x650+220+20")
root.title("Testing")
root.configure(borderwidth="1", relief="sunken",cursor="arrow",background="#BCC3B9",highlightcolor="black")
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)

frame2 = Frame(root, width=900, height=650)
frame1 = Frame(root, width=900, height=650)


#item 1 spinbox
Platform = Spinbox(values=("SX-16F", "SX-12VP", "SX-16VP", "VSRM-A", "NRNT-A", "FX-8", "DX-48V"), width="32")
Platform.place(x=500, y=200, relheight=0.05)

Button1=Button(frame1, text="Next", width =10, height= 2, bg= "#dbd8d7", command=lambda:swap_frame(frame2))
Button1.place(x=580, y=580)

Button3=Button(frame2, text="Back", width =10, height= 2, bg= "#dbd8d7", command=lambda:swap_frame(frame1))
Button3.place(x=580, y=580)

frame2.grid(row=0, column=0)
frame1.grid(row=0, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the master to your `Spinbox` widget. It currently defaults to `Tk` window which is only *initially* lifted, hence it gets blocked by both frames when either one is lifted. Replace:

```
Platform = Spinbox(values=(...), ...)
```

with:

```
Platform = Spinbox(frame1, values=(...), ...)
```

Comment: Thank you and nice explanation.